# How can i show our client that we need to build tools to reduce bugs and improve productivity

Tags: communication, productivity, software-development

I'm a software developer working outsourced to a client.

Currently our productivity is low due to lack of tools to automate recurring tasks, also due to the lack of common software base, each project is almost done from scratch or code is copied from previous projects.

For example, to update an existing webservice generated classes it can take up to 15 minutes, because the process is clumbersome and complex.It should take 2 mins max.

The customer mindset is, "i don't care how it's done as long as it works" and also very resistant to change.

Although we have freedom we still have deadlines specified by the customer's department. Only a couple of developers are worried but we have a lot a work to do and developing these things take time, the department should be concerned about these things and schedule time for these developments.It doesn't happened due to the established mindset.

How can we show that we need to develope these tools, methodologies or even have a manager or someone more dedicated to these subject s in order to make everything work well and improve our productivity?

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted.

Comment: What do you mean you have no manager? Even if you don't use this title, someone must be performing the equivalent role. Is that you?

Comment: It means there's a bunch of developers in the room that make code, each on their own way, each one can make builds on jenkins so later the batch process deploys the jenkin's builds and that's it. There's no one responsible, or at least with the job of making sure that everything is ok. Developers code, build and ship. We have people that have business knowledge,we have other teams that we interact with, but on our team, the team that develops the end product, there's no one responsible for the whole team.

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is lack of leadership. This is not something to address with a client, but rather within.

Comment: We still have deadlines to accomplish.

Comment: Are you perchance an autonomous collective?

Comment: The best description is "a team of autonomous individuals".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have been working like this for some time and limping along without a manager and proper hierarchy to make things more efficient then you can either

Live with it for your daily bread.

Get all the developers in to a consensus on how to do things and start using the tools that would streamline everything

Start your own business, do it properly, and steal the clients before someone else does.

Realistically everything that you have an issue with stems from not having a manager. If no one else has a problem with that, then you might be out of luck. I can also think of a scenario where it's beneficial for the company to continue doing things that way. If they partially calculate their billing based on developer hours for instance. Then the incentive to automate doesn't exist. There are companies who operate like this particularly if they have tied in clientele like govt departments etc,.

There is such a thing as 'automating yourself out of a job'. I've seen a new CEO come in, streamline a business to the point where they let half the staff go.

Comment: Thank for your empathetic answer!I feel like you understand me. I just didn't understand the last part well. Streamlining can get me fired or other's? Is that what you mean?

Comment: It's not as common as it used to be, but yes. Here's an example, X amount of developers take Y amount of time to do a job. After streamlining Y amount of time is halved. You no longer need X amount of developers to do that work, so you can save money and get rid of some, it's one of the main reasons for automating. Same thing happens on assembly lines, 10 men get replaced by one man and a robot machine.

Comment: I'm old, I remember when whole offices full of people were being replaced by computers and photocopiers, and companies would let 50 typists go in one day.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick your battles. It sounds to me like this automation, while *nice to have* is not critical to the job getting done.

At my current job I have a list a mile long of things which would be *nice to have*. For example, time to rewrite the entire Shipping system using newer technologies. But realistically, even though it works poorly, it *still works*. From a business perspective it's simply not a priority - although as a developer I cringe whenever I look at that steaming pile of crap we call a system.

So either make your point from a business perspective:

> By taking a week to do this now we will save X amount of time, and Y amount of money in the future.

Or learn to live without it.

Comment: Due to lake of automation and standardization we are more prone to make software bugs, so it's a little more than just a nice to have. In the business perspective, the company can be more competitve if i develop a product in one month instead of 6, the inefiency is that big... since only few (about 2 or 3) care about these problems, it looks like the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: @Calbertoferreira - explain this to your bosses, not to me. As I said, most managers care about dollars and cents. Thoroughly explain how valuable your tools would be in the long run, and how much ***money*** it will save the company. That's the only way to capture their attention.

Answer (score 0):

If the customer is of the attitude "as long as it works, I don't care how it is done", why don't you develop the tools that you need on your own terms ?

I mean if something is taking, say 2 days to develop today, without the tools and you know this will repeat frequently, when you have 3 or 4 of these 2 day long tasks in your task plan, why don't you spend the first, say 5 days, to develop your tool and then using your tool, deploy the tasks faster. And the next time something similar comes in, you can impress the customer by delivering the results in a matter of hours or minutes, rather than the expected 2 days.

If the customer is as much hands-off type you made them sound to be, this should work.

Comment: Because we have scheduled tasks, if we spend time developing tools we need to justify that time. In other words the customer needs to acknowledge we need time to perform these tasks.

Comment: To the department.

Comment: Then it's the department you need to persuade, not the customer.

Comment: The department doesn't care because at the the end it works, even if things take tons of time or bugs cripple in. I wanted them to see how wrong things are and how they can be improved but I'm not going to do anything without higher permission since I'm not the boss. I'm not going for such a huge effort knowing that other tasks can get delayed,it might come back and bite me despite my good intentions.